# Cross Compilation kernel and kernel modules problems

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, cross-compiling, kernel-module, mips32

I've been spending the last week trying to reach one objective that i still haven't reached.

**My final goal would be to cross-compile for some architectures** (in this question i will take as an example only one which is MIPSLE) **a couple of kernel modules that i'd like to use on my home router, by loading them at runtime with INSMOD.**

My router is missing of some iptables functionalities and that's why during the kernel compilation, who compiled it decided to get rid of them.

```
The current kernel version is quite obsolete: Linux version 2.6.36+ by doing /proc/version
```

I read a lot of documentations and still i'm not sure if it possible to compile just some modules or if it's necessary to compile the whole kernel everytime (some people said that for some modules is possible and for others with more dependencies is not, ***is that true ?***).

In this case the kernel modules i need are located in `/net/ipv4/netfilter/`

Since i didn't get how to compile just kernel modules in a standalone way, i decided to cross-compile the entire kernel and take the modules i needed.

So i've downloaded the proper toolchain (uclibc mipsle toolchain) and i was successfull in compiling a simple working hello world that i've executed on my router where i have an ssh shell.

**So i'm sure that the toolchain i'm using it's the correct one.**

---

Now, since i wanted to test with a recent version of kernel i've downloaded the latest ubuntu 20 with correspective kernel and i've successfully compiled it and the kernel modules that i was speaking about before, were there inside the netfilter folder in **.ko format** , PERFECT !

I clearly used the `/boot/config_file` of my host machine as `.config`

So, after I've downloaded the exact same kernel version that my router has (2.6.36) and I've tried to compile it with a .config file that i've found on GitHub related to a mipsle device with my same kernel version.

Here i think we have the first problem, I tried to find the `.config` of my device in order to have a smooth configuration but i don't have the `/boot` folder and in also was not in `/proc`.

How can i get it?

Anyway, I've used it and the compilation didn't look like failed, but these are the last lines:

```
  CC      drivers/usb/storage/usual-tables.o
  LD      drivers/usb/storage/usb-storage.o
  LD      drivers/usb/storage/built-in.o
  LD      drivers/usb/built-in.o
  LD      drivers/video/built-in.o
  LD      drivers/built-in.o
  LD      vmlinux.o
  MODPOST vmlinux.o
  GEN     .version
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  UPD     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/version.o
  LD      init/built-in.o
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux1
  KSYM    .tmp_kallsyms1.S
  AS      .tmp_kallsyms1.o
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux2
  KSYM    .tmp_kallsyms2.S
  AS      .tmp_kallsyms2.o
  LD      vmlinux
  SYSMAP  System.map
  SYSMAP  .tmp_System.map
  OBJCOPY arch/mips/boot/vmlinux.bin
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      drivers/scsi/scsi_wait_scan.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/scsi/scsi_wait_scan.ko
```

It says "1 Modules" but I don't understand why and inside the `/net/ipv4/netfilter` folder now I have `.o` files instead of `.ko` like if they've not been linked.

Since i was getting mad and I didn't know what to try more after several attempts, I've decided to use the config file of my host machine (ubuntu 2020, kernel 5.4.0.26) and the compilation was successful, **with `.ko` files inside the folder.**

The problem was that obviously they were modules compiled for x86-64 instead of MIPS and other clear "problems" related to the configuration of my x86-64 machine.

So, what i think now is that the `.config` I've found could be broken somehow, I also tried to disable, by adding a comment, that SCSI module, but nothing, I always get the same stuff.

And obviously between each try I always did a `make distclean` and `make clean`.

What do you suggest me to do? I won't even post all the references i've read about this stuff because i could sigsegv StackOverflow's server with that amount of data.

Thanks to everyone and sorry for the wall-post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i'm not sure if it possible to compile just some modules or if it's necessary to compile the whole kernel every time

Well, you can compile just single modules, but compiling a module requires the kernel to be already built. Once you do that one time though, you should be able to compile other modules singularly. That is, of course, if you do not wish to embed them in the kernel itself (`CONFIG_XXX=y` instead of `CONFIG_XXX=m`). You *should* be able to compile only the module you want like this (assuming `/path/to/linux` is the directory where your already built kernel source resides):

```
$ cd /path/to/linux
$ cd path/to/module/folder
$ make -C /path/to/linux M=$(pwd) modules
```

> I tried to find the `.config` of my device in order to have a smooth configuration but i don't have the `/boot` folder and it also was not in `/proc`. How can i get it?

Where did you look precisely? The presence of `/proc/config.gz` depends on [`CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/IKCONFIG_PROC.html) ([see also here](https://superuser.com/a/538110/591004)). If you cannot find the file then it's most likely because that configuration option was disabled when the kernel was built. You may try look under `/boot` (as you already did), or under `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/.config`, but unfortunately there's not much else to do otherwise.

I've seen people [suggest](https://superuser.com/a/1011993/591004) trying to run `modprobe configs` and then check `/proc/config.gz`, but that seems strange since as far as I know the kernel config shouldn't be configurable to be available as a loadable module.

> What do you suggest me to do?

Well, the most important thing you want right now is to find the configuration file for your router (or a compatible one). If you cannot find that, it will be pretty hard to get everything right. You might want to search for OpenWRT versions available for your router (if any), or really anywhere else on the internet as long as you can find a suitable configuration. Include your router brand and/or model in your searches. StackOverflow can't really help you that much about this though.

You can try cross-compiling a 5.4 kernel with default config plus the module you want. For example, assuming you have the right cross-compilation toolchain ready:

```
cd /path/to/linux
make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=your-cross-toolchain-prefix- defconfig
make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=your-cross-toolchain-prefix- menuconfig

# ... enable the module, tune the config ...

make -j ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=your-cross-toolchain-prefix-
```

In any case, consider the fact that jumping from a 2.6 to a 5.4 kernel is a pretty big change, and it's likely to end up breaking everything, so be sure to make a backup of your router's firmware before trying anything.

Comment: Hi Marco, thank you for your answer

I did as you said and i was ok in compiling the kernel modules that i wanted (i also had to make a Makefile to compile them even after the kern compilation bcause it was not done automatically.)
Anyway, the .ko now if i run file is exactly the same as one of any .ko that was inside the router. But if i execute it with insmod ( there is not modprobe) i get an error:
"insmod: cannot insert test.ko': Success"

instead with a kernel module that was already in the router, if i execute them it returns nothing and with lsmod i can see it running. why?

Comment: @Luke I cannot say what's wrong without looking at the code. I would suggest you to ask a new question posting the code of the test.ko module that you are building. If insmod fails like that it usually means that the module returned something other than 0 from its init function. In this case though it says "Success" which is what 0 means... so I am confused. Can't say much more though.

Comment: @Luke that doesn't make any sense. A file called `config.sh` has nothing to do with kernel configuration and it's most likely a shell script. Don't use it. Also, why is the module called `test.ko` that's a pretty strange module name. Again, it's impossible to say anything without more details. I hope I solved the question(s) you had in this post, for anything else you should create a new question.

Comment: Thanks , for the answer.

The source of the kernel module is the original one of the kernel itself (netfilter module)

i've managed to find partially the config file, i'll try to see if i can get a proper configuration to build the kernel tho.

grazie :)

P.s = test.ko was a random name i give to the original iptables_nat.ko module.

yeah .sh should be script but i'm sure this is a partial kernel config. i don't know what weird stuff the developers where doing here.

Comment: @Luke there is no `test.ko` in the `Makefile` of the module folder you mention in your post. Not sure what you're doing really. What specific kernel version is the one that you are working on? Maybe I have a different one.

Comment: sorry maybe by writing that test.ko i've confused you. It was just an example name. The 3 modules i'm trying to build are :

1) iptable_filter.ko
2) iptable_nat.ko
3) ip_tables.ko

this is the config.sh that was inside /sbin : https://pastebin.com/YAi7FTts

as you can see it's a proper but cutted config file.

the fact is that there are several other .sh files which are real script that probably use that config.sh to build a real .config (this is my guess).

also in one of these i've found tracks of this : https://github.com/dt99/mt7615/blob/master/mt_wifi/embedded/Makefile

Comment: @Luke that starts to make more sense. You may try to do `defconfig` and then try using `/scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh` to merge `.config` with the file you found.

Comment: Yeah i had the same, idea, also in that config file, apparently they are using another toolchain that i've found on a github repository. I'll try to use that one which looks the proper one instead of the generic uclibc one.
i'll let you know ! grazie marco, molto gentile :)